# Change toolbar according to Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I want to change the top `toolbar` according to clicked `fragment` but it seems not working for me.
What I want is when I click the `fragment`, the top toolbar should change. For example, add a `Add` button and change the title of the toolbar for `Create Fragment`.

Fragment.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event_created, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar123 = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar123);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar123);
        //((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
        return v;
    }
```

Fragment XML

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.rick.check_in.ui.EventCreatedFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar123"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#131313"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#00aaaaaa">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you use button inside Toolbar? I mean, it's not wrong but you can use menu items with icons instead of buttons, and fragments can have their own menus. If you wish to change color or similar features of Toolbar you can create a method inside activity and invoke that method from fragments using Activity instance.

Comment: I don't see any point in your code where you have tried doing this.

Comment: @Thracian so you means i just have to set the menu item icons for different fragments(for example, set title, set the layout of menu item on the toolbar)? It is possible to customize different toolbar (different toolbar xml) for different fragments and set the layout of different toolbar according to different fragment ?

Comment: I've seen Dinesh Neupane's answer but it's not right way to do. You should not access to views of Activity from fragment. You should get Activity instance and set view properties using a method or methods

Yes, you can change title and other features if you set that method inside your Activity that contains fragments. You can also change menus, in your situation the button using different menus for fragments. You can almost never see a view of Activity accessed from a fragment, it's doable but not recommended. Way to keep things separate, less coupled is to use callback, or Activity instance

Comment: ToolBar should be view of Activity and Activity should have fragments inside it's ViewPager  if you wish to toggle fragments on swipe gesture. Do not put ToolBar inside fragment. Check Toolbar samples you will see the pattern to build proper material design layouts.

Comment: @Thracian guess I will use the Thracian idea by putting one toolbar on the activity and invoke the method to change title, menu items according to fragment. Btw I have solve the above issue, I didn't call the fragment instances on my activity. Thats why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this way. `onAttach(Activity)` called once the fragment is associated with its activity.

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {


    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    private Toolbar toolbar123;


    public YourFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mainActivity = (MainActivity)activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event_created, container, false);
        toolbar123 = (Toolbar)v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar123);
        setupToolbar();
        return v;
    }

    private void setupToolbar(){
        toolbar123.setTitle(getString("Your Fragment Title"));
        mainActivity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar123);
    }

}
```